# Git synchronize a specific branch folder Rundeck

Tags: git, azure-devops, rundeck

Is it possibile to synchronize a git branch's folder with ssh?

https://company.visualstudio.com/company-TO-DevOps/_git/_DevOps-Automation?path=%2FRundeck

I want to sync a specific folder under the branch, not all folders...

user@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:v3/company-TO-DevOps/_git/_DevOps-Automation >>> RUNDECK FOLDER

Alternative solution is to create another branch dedicated to this task, but I'd like to use the existing one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rundeck, for each project you can specify where the projects write files in the SCM section.

Projet settings-->Setup SCM (Import or Export) --> Job Source Files --> File Path Template

Default path
${job.group}${job.name}-${job.id}.${config.format}

I've change in this

Rundeck_Projects/Azure_DevOps/${job.group}${job.name}.${config.format}

Now under my branch I have all job in their folder in Yaml format.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please accept your solution [as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unsure what you mean by branch's folder,
but I'm pretty sure the answer is no.

A branch is just a pointer to a commit, which represents a state for *all* the tracked files in the repository. Git branches are not related to directories.

Comment: I mean to point to a branch subfolder, not the root. I'm using Rundeck for automation and I've synchronized a repo branch, but I don't want it write in the root, I want it to write a specific folder. I've solved with a configuration option in Rundeck. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: under file path template of SCM RUNDECK configuration you have to specify which folder to use. Rundeck_Projects/Azure_DevOps/${job.group}${job.name}.${config.format}

Comment: @Cyber.Drunk Thanks for sharing your solution here,can you convert it from comment to answer?So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood [this article](http://scriptedonachip.com/git-sparse-checkout) right, a sparse checkout might be what you want. With this command you can clone a specific pattern as [the documentation states](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout#_full_pattern_set). You could create -if I am not mistaken- a file like a gitignore but in your case it would just have your path to the folder you want to clone like this

```
/PATH-TO-YOUR-FOLDER/*
```

after you created the /sparse-checkout file via `git sparse-checkout init`. After this every pull should automatically just pull the folder. With `git sparse-checkout disable` you could clone the whole repo then.

Please note that the docs state that this is a experimental feature.